# Delay playing AVI with OpenCv

Tags: opencv, delay, avi

Im playing an avi through opencv and im trying to do some circle detection on the video. just playing the video is grand but when i try to detect circles, the video slows down. is there any way to get keep the video playing near the speed it was recorded at?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    IplImage*img;
   int key=0;

 CvCapture*capture = cvCaptureFromAVI("C:\\Users\\Nathan\\Desktop\\SnookVid.wmv");

 if(!capture) return 1;

int fps = (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);

cvNamedWindow("circles", 0);


while(key!='q'){
    img = cvQueryFrame( capture );

    if(!img) break;


IplImage* gray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
//IplImage* hsv = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

//covert to grayscale
cvCvtColor(img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

// This is done so as to prevent a lot of false circles from being detected
cvSmooth(gray, gray, CV_GAUSSIAN, 3, 5);

IplImage* canny = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
//IplImage* rgbcanny = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
//cvCanny(gray, canny, 50, 70, 3);

//detect circles
CvSeq* circles = cvHoughCircles(gray, storage, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 27, 70, 40,0,0);
//cvCvtColor(canny, rgbcanny, CV_GRAY2BGR);
//cvCvtColor(img,hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);
//draw all detected circles
float* p;
CvScalar s;
int num_red = 22;
for (int i = 0; i < circles->total; i++)
{
     // round the floats to an int
     p = (float*)cvGetSeqElem(circles, i);
     cv::Point center(cvRound(p[0]), cvRound(p[1]));
     int radius = cvRound(p[2]);

     //uchar* ptr;
     //ptr = cvPtr2D(img, center.y, center.x, NULL);
     //printf("B: %d G: %d R: %d\n", ptr[0],ptr[1],ptr[2]);


     s = cvGet2D(img,center.y, center.x);//colour of circle
    printf("B: %f G: %f R: %f\n",s.val[0],s.val[1],s.val[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try reducing the image size before processing it with `HoughCircles` with either [pyrDown](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=pyrdown#void%20pyrDown%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20const%20Size&%20dstsize%29) or [resize](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=resize#void%20resize%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20Size%20dsize,%20double%20fx,%20double%20fy,%20int%20interpolation%29).

If you want to use the detected circles with the original image, multiply the radius and center by the factor you divided the image. A 2x scale reduction should give you a 2-4x speedup in processing time minus the time it takes to perform the scale operation.

Below is a short example of how you might go about this:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat circleBig = imread("circle.png", 0);
    Mat circleSmall;

    double scale = 2.0;

    // INTER_NEAREST is crude, but very fast; you may need INTER_LINEAR here...
    resize(circleBig, circleSmall, Size(0, 0), 1.0 / scale, 1.0 / scale, cv::INTER_NEAREST);

    cvtColor(circleBig, circleBig, CV_GRAY2RGB);

    vector<Vec3f> circles;
    HoughCircles(circleSmall, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, circleSmall.rows >> 2, 200, 100 );

    for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
    {
         Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][3]));
         int radius = cvRound(circles[i][4]);
         // draw the circle center
         circle( circleBig, scale*center, 3, Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
         // draw the circle outline
         circle( circleBig, scale*center, scale*radius, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8, 0 );
    }

    imshow("circleBig", circleBig);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Finally, here is the test image I used:
[image: circle.png]

Here are the timings I got for a `HoughCircles` detection:

```
640x480 time: 0.0127101
320x240 time: 0.00408843
```

Roughly, a 3x speedup! :)

Comment: i have put in my code above. How would i resize the whole video?

Comment: Just resize one frame at a time before you call the `HoughCircles` function. You don't have to resize the entire video before you start processing, so you would resize your `img` matrix to an `imgSmall` matrix and compute `HoughCircles` on `imgSmall` like in my example.

Comment: so would just put      resize(circleBig, circleSmall, Size(0, 0), 1.0 / scale, 1.0 / scale, cv::INTER_NEAREST);    after cvQueryFrame(capture)

Comment: Yeah, but don't mix the C and C++ APIs if you can help it. Use `cvResize`. It's documentation is in the link I posted for `resize` as well.

Comment: there is no specified scaling factor in resize for the c api. does that matter?

Comment: I think it just uses the size that you allocate for the `dst` matrix as the target for the resize operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try mevatron's suggestion, it will certainly make a difference and that's why I upvoted it.

But one thing that needs to be clear to you is: the video slowing down is not a bug of in your source code, its also not a bug in OpenCV. This effect is caused by your CPU having to spend processing time to perform the circle detection for every frame of the video. Your CPU simply can't perform this task fast enough to give you the sensation of real-time.

The title of the question is a bit misleading since you are not just playing an AVI with OpenCV.